# Python xml parsing problem

Tags: python, xml, parsing, sax

could you please explain me the error below, and give me a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Apr 14 2011, 20:41:59)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from xml.sax import make_parser
>>> p = make_parser()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/_xmlplus/sax/sax2exts.py", line 37, in make_parser
    return XMLParserFactory.make_parser(parser_list)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/_xmlplus/sax/saxexts.py", line 75, in make_parser
    sys.modules[parser_name].create_parser = _create_parser
KeyError: 'xml.sax.drivers2.drv_pyexpat'
>>>
```

Comment: Without seeing the program that causes the error, we cannot explain it. Now please don't post the entire program, but try to identify the part that causes the problem, and post just that. See [here](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If I open the python interactive shell, and give the 2 lines above, I get this error message. No more code.

Comment: You really have to use Python 2.4.3? :)

Comment: @user: Which OS/distribution are you running on? Which version of `expat` do you have installed?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot influence the OS environment and python version. :( Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga), expat-1.95.8-8.3.el5_5.3

Comment: Do you have root access? If so you can install new RPMs.

Comment: @user777377 https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2011-January/msg00072.html

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be with your python version and python library.

Have a look [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-83688.html)

Comment: What is a "python blender"? Sorry for the stupid question, but I haven't found any relevant with google...

Comment: blender is library, actually version of your python library is not compatible with your python version..

Comment: Is there any workaround with the limiting condition, that I cannot change the versions?

Comment: Try installing different version of library

Comment: I am not allowed to do that. :(